# Does anyone have absorption coefficients at different wavelengths for sulfur dioxide?

Tags: atmosphere, geophysics, open-data, reference-request

Does anyone have absorption coefficients for sulfur dioxide at various wavelengths?

Comment: Welcome to EarthScience.SE. Please specify, which resources you used to try to answer the question on your own. Which literature did you read?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as 'very low-quality'

Comment: Sulfur dioxide *where*? In the air?

Answer (score 5):

The [US National Institute of Standards and Technology](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7446095&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=0) is a good source. The following image show absorbance between 2.5 and 32 $\mu$m. For wavelengths shorter than 2.5 $\mu$m, other sources (less reliable) suggest that there is no significant absorption bands.
[image]
The original data in ASCII JCAMP-DX format can be downloaded [here](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?JCAMP=C7446095&Index=0&Type=IR).

Comment: @bpl1960 I'm glad it was useful. It was the infrared absorption spectrum what you were looking for? If this solved you question feel free to accept the answer unless you want to encourage other answers for a while.